# How to convert a SVG into JSON which can be saved in backend and then again call the JSON and convert it to SVG

Tags: svg

As i was working on a developing tool and there were many svg's in the playground so that the dom becoming heavy and like to save the svg's in the back-end and when ever the need i need to drop it in the playground.......
Can anyone has a solution...........

For example i'm giving a SVG

```
<svg width="300" height="200"> <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;"/></svg
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the SVG an ID:

```
<svg id="svgID" width="300" height="200"> <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;"/></svg>
```

Remeber that no elements can have the same ID

### Convert SVG to JSON String

Then use JavaScript to create the JSON string

```
//Get the SVG
var svg = document.getElementById("svgID");

//Creates a temporary div and append the SVG to it, this is not visible to the user
var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
tempDiv.appendChild(svg);

//Gets the svg as a string
var svgText = tempDiv.innerHTML;

//Create the JSON string
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(svgText);
```

You'll get a string that looks like this:

### To convert it back again

```
//Get the svgString from JSON
svgText = JSON.parse(jsonString);

//Creates a SVG Node from the string
tempDiv.innerHTML = svgText

//Puts the SVG into the element with the id "playgroundID"
document.getElementById("playgroundID").append(tempDiv.firstChild);
```